# RPGLE - CL data types comparison

Tags: types, ibm-midrange, rpgle

I'm asking myself what is the correct comparison of data types between RPGLE and CL in IBMi.

So:

```
*DEC  <> Packed numeric (es DCL-S ... PACKED(7:0))
*CHAR <> Fixed length string (es DCL-S ... CHAR(10))
*LGL  <> Indicator (es DCL-S ... IND)
*PTR  <> Pointer (es DCL-S ... POINTER)
```

What I'm missing are `*INT` and `*UINT`.
Reading IBM Knowledge Center I found:

> For character or integer CL variables, specify the number of bytes for
>   the CL variable.

Then, are them `BINDEC` (in positional it's `B`) or `INT/UNS` (`I/U`) data types?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

CL supports *INT and *UINT types
[Declaring variables to a CL program or procedure](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_ibm_i_72/rbam6/declv.htm)

Which correspond directly to RPG's INT/UNS types.

Do not ever use RPG's BINDEC type.  It's an obsolete hack from before RPG supported true integer types.

Comment: Hi! Mmmh if they correspond to INT/UNS, why am I able to use a 5I 0 in rpgle and not in a CL?

Comment: RPG's integers are defined by digits, CL's integer is defined by bytes.  TYPE(*INT) LEN(2)  == 5i 0